# Find all selected words in a given text

Tags: go

I have the below code, where I want the user to enter some key words, then find what from these words are exisiting in a given string, but the resulting `matches` slice is an empty slice of a length equal to text to be checked
[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/rKqZASatzJC)

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    p := []string{}
    p = append(p, "engineer")
    p = append(p, "doctor")
    var skills string
    for _, z := range p {
        skills += `|` + z
    }
    fmt.Println(skills)
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?i)` + skills)

    matches := re.FindAllString("I'm an engineer not a doctor", -1)
    fmt.Println(matches)
    for i, j := range matches {
        fmt.Println(i, j)
    }
}
```

Comment: try strings.Contains or strings.Index instead. more efficient.

Comment: Remove the leading `|` from the pattern: `skills := strings.Join([]string{"engineer", "doctor"}, "|")`

Comment: Thanks @CeriseLimón

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments provided, I got is as:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    p := []string{}
    p = append(p, "engineer")
    p = append(p, "doctor")
    p = append(p, "chemical (permit)")
    skills := strings.Join(p, "|")
    
    fmt.Println(skills)
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?i)` + skills)

    matches := re.FindAllString("I'm an engineer not a doctor who is getting chemical permits", -1)
    fmt.Println(matches, len(matches))
    for i, j := range matches {
        fmt.Println(i, j)
    }
}
```

The output is:

```sh
engineer|doctor|chemical (permit)
[engineer doctor chemical permit] 3
0 engineer
1 doctor
2 chemical permit
```